# Do I need to do anything after receiving a Form 5498?

Tags: united-states, income-tax

I just received a Form 5498 for the 2014 tax year. It shows that I contributed to a Roth IRA but not to an IRA, SEP, or SIMPLE account, and that I did not take any distributions from any retirement account. Is this form just for my records, or do I need to recalculate my taxes in some way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The form is just for your records. You do not need to adjust your tax return.  From the article "[What is Form 5498](https://turbotax.intuit.com/tax-tools/tax-tips/IRS-Tax-Forms/What-Is-IRS-Form-5498--IRA-Contributions-Information-/INF20121.html)":

> Form 5498: IRA Contributions Information reports your IRA
>   contributions to the IRS. Your IRA trustee or issuer – not you – is
>   required to file this form with the IRS by May 31. You won't find this
>   form in TurboTax, nor do you file it with your tax return. The copy
>   you receive in the mail is a copy for your records.

It's a good idea to verify that the amount reported on the form (box 1) matches what you actually contributed.